# Interpreting contemporary literature

Tags: american-english, literature

There's something I just don't get of English usage in contemporary literature. Take the following excerpt:

> I have only to break into the tightness of a strawberry, and I see
>   summer-its dust and lowering skies.

What does that even mean? Is that sentence even grammatically correct? I would have to assume so, since it's from one of the most famous writings of Toni Morrison.

How do I even begin interpreting such paragraph?

Comment: There's nothing ungrammatical; it may be nonsensical, however.

Comment: The title of your post is leading astray. - There are only two conspicuous things in this sentence: the verb  "break" and the noun group "lowering skies". "break" can only be a metaphor for "to bite"  and "lowering skies"  is a bit mysterious. Maybe Morrision thinks of a sky with a lot oh large white clouds, which might give the impression  that the sky ceiling is lower.

Comment: @rogermue: The only credible *verb* usage of ***to lower*** I know of that seems relevant here is the sense of *to scowl*. It may also be spelled ***lour***, and it's very often used somewhat more figuratively (of the sky, for example) to mean , *to look threatening* (i.e. - dark clouds, suggestive of bad weather to come). Admittedly that seems an *unlikely* allusion for OP's context - but that's a matter of Lit Crit interpretation, not really relevant to ELU.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's Lit Crit (of a poetic, non-idiomatic usage with no single unambiguous meaning).

Comment: @FumbleFingers - How to lower blood pressure. - See Collins Dic  lower, verb http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/lower

Comment: @rogermue: That *transitive* sense is the most common one, but it doesn't really work even with something like *This play was so bad the best thing about it was the lowering curtain at the end of the final act*. And although it's true we do have (metaphoric) usages such as *You look like the sky has fallen* (i.e. - *downcast*), I can't see any chance OP's example is a reference to *falling skies*.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't call it nonsensical -- it's literary writing.  Because writers of literature are free to break all the rules, it's unfair to apply grammatical standards to their work.

That being said, here's how I would interpret it.

"I have only to break into the tightness of a strawberry, and I see summer-its dust and lowering skies."

It's a sense memory.  When the speaker bites into a strawberry, s/he is brought back to an earlier time of summer, and for him/her, that includes dust and "lowering skies," so it's not a completely happy memory.

Comment: How did you know the speaker is biting a strawberry? (Unless "breaking" into a food is a common phrase for taking a bite),

Comment: It's literature. It doesn't have to use common phrases. In fact, good writers will try to use language in original ways and avoid common usage in order to intensify what they are saying. How do three of  us respondents (so far) know break means "bite"? As Rogermue comments, what else could it mean?

Answer (score 1):

> How did you know the speaker is biting a strawberry?

If Morrison had written, "I have only to break *off* the tightness of a strawberry," then we might have thought of picking a strawberry.  The *into* is what makes us conclude the strawberry is being eaten.

About the *tightness*.  Consider that when plant cells are well hydrated and turgid, the cell wall encloses all that moist cytoplasm *tightly*.  I think this is how Morrison is thinking about the strawberry.  Which strictly speaking isn't really accurate, in my opinion.  There are some ripe fruits which, when punctured, immediately dribble sweet juice.  But I don't think the strawberry is like that.  A ripe plum would be.  Anyway, it's a nice image, regardless.

Now, the lowering.  The next sentence in the novel is "It remains for me a season of storms."

Random House 2010 definition of lowering, first sense:

> dark and threatening: *lowering skies*

So that part is pretty easy to understand.

But you asked about the grammar.  Here's the original sentence again:

> I have only to break into the tightness of a strawberry, and I see
>   summer---its dust and lowering skies.

Which is equivalent to

> All I have to do is break into the tightness of a strawberry, and I start to remember, and see in my mind's eye, the things that I remember about summer from those days. My most vivid visual memories from that time are dust, and skies that looked like a storm was coming.

Does that help you understand the original better?

Answer (score 0):

> lowering skies

I'd take this to mean

> **lowering:** used to ​describe the ​sky when it is very ​dark and it ​looks as if it is about to ​rain - *[Cambridge dictionaries](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/lowering)*

I'd agree with ewormuth's interpretation.